# helm install vs helm uninstall - .Release.IsInstall variable

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I am currently using the helm `.Release.IsInstall` variable https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/ in my helm chart.  Here's the snippet of code that I have:

```
       {{- if .Release.IsInstall }}
       command: [ "python", "main.py", "install"]
       {{- else }}
       command: [ "python", "main.py", "delete"]
       {{- end }}
```

However regardless of whether I run `helm install` or `helm uninstall` it seems as though `.Release.IsInstall` returns a boolean of `true`.  Basically I am attempting to detect whether the user is doing an install/uninstall.  Maybe there is another variable that I should be using instead.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Release.IsInstall` only works during the installation process. When you're running `helm uninstall,` the Helm chart templates aren't evaluated, so this variable isn't relevant in that context. Therefore, you can't use `.Release.IsInstall` to detect an uninstall operation directly.

Since Helm doesn't evaluate templates on uninstall, it's not straightforward to pass different commands for uninstalling using the chart templates.

One common approach to handle this is using Helm `pre-uninstall` and `post-uninstall` hooks. You can define specific jobs or pods that run before or after the uninstall process, for example you can use a `pre-delete` hook to perform actions before the chart is deleted, and `post-delete` for actions after the chart is deleted.

```
kind: Job
apiVersion: batch/v1
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-pre-delete"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-delete
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pre-delete
        image: python:3.8
        command: ["python", "main.py", "delete"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```